# Why don't the citizens use the underground port and factory to escape the Birdcage?

Tags: one-piece

People can use the lift to go down. The Birdcage wouldn't possibly be deep enough. Also, the cage won't do any harm since it is a port and there is sea-water. The path can be created by any strong character to lead to the uderground place like Fujitora, Chin Jao, etc.

Also the Scrapheap where Kanjuro was held could also be used for refuge!

This is the depth of the underground space:

[image: underground Port and Scrapheap]

Why isn't Oda using it?

Comment: On a related note, while googling the one piece birdcage, I found that the birdcage has been up for a full year now

Answer (score 6):

[image]

It would not make sense for them to go down there. Most of the citizens don't even know about the underground port and everybody also witnessed Pica's strength. **If they would go down there they would be sitting ducks.** Doflamingo would be able to throw attacks at them and use Parasite until they all die, or Pica would be able to just bury them all alive.

Keep in mind that we know more than the people in One Piece know. **Most people don't know about the port and a lot of people don't know about the sharpness of the cage.** Normal citizens in general don't know about the port, because it was always kept secret, while those that were turned into toys, have a big grudge against Doflamingo and would be going straight for him to take revenge. There was also a short time period where the citizens believed Doflamingo and wanted to end the game by capturing the *criminals*.

Dressrosa is a pretty big country and is in a state of confusion. Aside from the fact that **they just wouldn't all fit in there**, most citizens take the most logical decision and that is running away from the most imminent treat. Those at the suburbs would notice the cage coming closer and would run towards the city center, while those at the city center, would see the Donquixote family being close and would try to run towards the cage as they don't know it is closing in and is as sharp as it is. **The citizens are powerless and would just run until this is all over.**

Additionally, the tunnel under Dressrosa is filled with water, so they either have to swim out of there, or take a boat. Since there are many people that cannot swim (elderly, kids, even adults, Devil Fruit users), they should all be carried or taken on a ship. Yet most citizens don't even know how to navigate a ship and there just are not enough ships available to carry everybody. **So in any case many would have to be left behind.**

When they would eventually reach the outskirts of the country, they should go somewhere. Yet they are in open sea, so there is nowhere to go. The only thing they could do is, build a tunnel upwards or make a net to climb the huge boulders and wait until the fight is over. While this on its own sounds very unlikely to be done, when they get out, **Doflamingo would just redo the birdcage** over the entire island, destroy the tunnel/net and start over from the beginning.

Comment: Also birdage might start from some meters under the ground, we don't know how deep it is in the ground.

Comment: If they are instructed to run to the center of the cage or push the cage,etc. , why not instruct them to go underground and swim to the edge of dressrosa where they can be out of the cage? Then the likes of fujitora,zoro,etc. can defend them from attacks... Your answer is on a defensive note... Not convincing... Also Oda is a genius! He should have atleast showed that such a trick is not possible because of some reasons you mentioned above! I think he either ignored or forgot the fact of the underground port!

Comment: @abhishah901  Your plan doesn't make sense on many levels and would result in the deaths of many, but I'll stick to the main point. Swimming is absurd, because many can't even swim and they would have to swim through the pretty long tunnel and all the way to the next island, which is impossible. So I assume, they should take the merchants' ships. This is also impossible, because there are not enough ships to carry everyone, so again many would be left behind and that is assuming many citizens can navigate ships.Even if they reach the edge of the cage, there is just nowhere to go from there

Comment: As you said many are citizens and so wont have any devil fruits(well,most of them).. The others can carry the Devil Fruit eaters like how Sanji,usopp and zoro help Luffy,chopper,etc. when they fall of the ship. And there's no need to go to another island! The citizens just have to be on the same island! the birdcage will have shriken a bit and the citizens just have stay on the outskirts! They have to rely on Luffy and other fighters to beat the shit out of Doffy.. Just like they are doing now but from the outside! That's it! I'm just saying that Oda never considered this possibility and why?

Comment: @abhishah901 I was talking about old, young and injured people. Those cannot swim. The tunnel will go out to the sea, so are you saying the citizens will create a tunnel, while swimming in the tunnel all the way to the surface and when Doflamingo sees this he will just ignore it? I dont buy that. The citizens are too weak to build a tunnel and when Doffy sees them outside he will just create a new cage because he wants to kill them all